# Woocommerce Order / AFC get_sub_field / get_sub_field_object (array)

Tags: php, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

Have setup ACF repeater field that stores various amount of tracking numbers in the order. Having 0 success with retrieving this information so need some advice.

Am using this to put information in subfields and it does the job

```
foreach ($base->DocumentLines->DocumentLine as $item) {

    foreach ($item->MiscData as $misc) {

        foreach ($misc->PackageNo as $package) {

            $trackno = (string)$package->TrackingNo;

            update_post_meta("$order_id", $field_rep, $count);

            $sub = $count +1;

            update_sub_field(array($field_key_rep, $sub, $field_key_sub), $trackno, "$order_id");

            $count = $count + 1;

            update_field($field_key, $trackno, "$order_id");

        }
    }
}
```

This works well, but then i need to retrieve this numbers and write em out. They are getting included in an email so need to retrieve the data outside of order.

Before rebuilding the function to be able to handle multiple numbers i did use a single field and could retrieve the information with

```
get_post_meta($order_id, 'tracking', true);
```

Feels like i have been trying everything now but got absolutely nothing.

Image from one of the orders, in this one it’s 10 tracking numbers but it varies from 1 to 20 if it's to any help.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The feeling when you realize after 10 hours that your missed a capital letter in sub field name.

Just wanted to submit my solution and hopefully it can help someone else having issues with **ACF Repeater fields + Woocommerce**

For my specific case i did make a function that could extract all the tracking numbers my function above did add from XML files.

```
$function trackingNo($postID) {

    $field_rep = 'trackingNo';
    $field_sub = 'no';

    if (have_rows($field_rep, $postID)) {

        $trackingNo = array();

    // loop through the rows of data
    while (have_rows($field_rep, $postID)):
        the_row();

        // Add to array
        $trackingNo[] = get_sub_field($field_sub);

    endwhile;

    $foo = implode('&consignmentId=', $trackingNo);
    $bar = 'urlzz/tracktrace/TrackConsignments_do.jsp?&consignmentId=';

    $value = $bar . $foo;

    return $value;
 }
}
```

Any advice for improvement is always welcome, my PHP is so'n'so :)